Angular Material: Runtime generate theme
I need to somehow generate a Angular Material theme on runtime. I get two colors passed via query params and need to adopt them to the theme. Is this somehow possible? Or just by checking how the theming works internally and replace all the css variables?

Yes, it is possible. There is an active issue on Github regarding runtime theme generation. You can utilize system variables to change color and font properties dynamically. The theme object supports a use-system-variables property:
$your-theme: mat.define-theme((
  color: (
    theme-type: light,
    primary: mat.$blue-palette,
    tertiary: mat.$red-palette,
    use-system-variables: true,
  ),
  typography: (
    use-system-variables: true
  ),
));

Please notice that this is, as of now, not well documented. You can find some useful system variables (called tokens) in the GitHub issue and the _m3-tokens.scss files.

Wow, thank you pretty much! Was this already possible with mat-2? The current solution relys on it ...
